# "panel3" not found in same unit-SOLVED

Tags: panel

I wrote a program in Lazarus 3.2 with a few panels,all in the same unit.
I want to display one at a time,so I want to hide the others with a procedure.
I got error messages:
identifier not found "panel 3"
identifier not found "panel 6"
below is the code:

```
procedure HidePanels;
begin
    panel2.hide;
    panel3.hide;
    panel6.hide;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    HidePanels;
    panel2.left:=120;
    panel2.top:=8;
    panel2.show;
end;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

if I put the code line from the HidePnels proceddure in
each procedure that needs to hide other panels,
the code works, but that's more code than I should have.

Made one change in HidePanels procdeure and it works:

change
panel2.hide;
to
Form1.panel2.hide;

since it's part of form1

should work with other resources, too.

Comment: Please do not post the answer inside the question. Instead post the answer as such below the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer